# sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I Use `flask-SQLAlchemy` to create databases, but I get this error:

> "sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError
> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.refund - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression."

I have a `User` model schema defined as:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    location = db.Column(db.String(64))
    about_me = db.Column(db.Text())
    member_since = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    avatar_hash = db.Column(db.String(32))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    purchases = db.relationship("Purchase", backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    refund = db.relationship("Refund", backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

class Refund(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Refund"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    purchase_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Purchase.id"))
    medicine_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("inventory.medicine_id"))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: You have other tables as seen in your `db.relationship()` calls. The `Refund` model is correctly associated with the `User` table. So, there is a likelihood that the error you are getting stems from how you are creating the relationship with/between other models.

Comment: Perhaps you want an FK to `users` in the `Refund` model?

Answer (score 1):

Because for `db.ForeignKey("Purchase.id")`, there actually needs to be a foreign key connection in your database. This error is caused because in your database there isn't any foreign key linking to a primary key (or not correctly) so you gotta fix your tables in your database.